# How to return promises from action creators of react redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, promise

I am trying to return array length from **redux action creator**. But I am getting **undefined**.

***component.js***

```
componentDidMount = () => {

   this
       .props
       .getMyData()
       .then(responseFromAction => {
           console.log("Response from Action :", responseFromAction)
        })
       .catch(err => {
           console.log("catch->", err)
       })
}
```

***Action.js***

```
export const getMyData = () => {

  return async (dispatch, getState) => {

     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        axios
          .get(
               API_URL
          )
          .then(async res => {
               if(res.data.success) {
                  const payload = res.data.myData;

                  dispatch({
                     type : SET_MY_DATA,
                     payload,
                  });

                  resolve(res.data.myData.length);

                }
                else {
                   reject();
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                reject()
            })   
        })
    }
}
```

I think I should get the length of an data array from server but instead I am getting '**undefined**' in component.js

Comment: Did you try putting `console.log(res.data.myData)`?

Comment: There's also a bug - if `res.data.success` is falsy, the function will never resolve. Perhaps you'll want to put an `else { reject() }`.

Comment: @RahulDwivedi console.log(res.data.myData) is giving correct data. and in redux state, it is set as expected. Only problem is component.js part where response is undefined.

Comment: @cbr thank you for pointing out. I will update my code

Comment: If the data is correct in `redux state`, same data will be passed to your component via it. where are your getting data in component from?

Comment: Also what does `async` doing in `then`? you're not awaiting anything inside that.

Comment: I think you should try redux-thunk, is made exactly for this purpouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using an async keyword with the inner function in action creator, you are actually returning promise as response to the `.then` of getMyData.

You can easily resolve your problem by removing the async keyword

```
export const getMyData = () => {

  return (dispatch, getState) => {

     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        axios
          .get(
               API_URL
          )
          .then(async res => {
               if(res.data.success) {
                  const payload = res.data.myData;

                  dispatch({
                     type : SET_MY_DATA,
                     payload,
                  });

                  resolve(res.data.myData.length);

                }
                else {
                   reject();
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                reject()
            })   
        })
    }
}
```

or if you choose to go with the async keyword, perhaps you could use await with the inner promise and then return the value

```
export const getMyData = () => {

  return async (dispatch, getState) => {

     const length = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        axios
          .get(
               API_URL
          )
          .then(async res => {
               if(res.data.success) {
                  const payload = res.data.myData;

                  dispatch({
                     type : SET_MY_DATA,
                     payload,
                  });

                  resolve(res.data.myData.length);

                }
                else {
                   reject();
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                reject()
            })   
        });

       return length;
    }
}
```